# In what sense is this a feedback control?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, time-evolution, metrology

I am reading a couple of papers on control enhanced parameter estimation. One is titled "[Optimal Feedback Scheme and Universal Time Scaling for Hamiltonian Parameter Estimation](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.115.110401)" (arXiv version [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.07050)) and the other is "[Sequential Feedback Scheme Outperforms the Parallel Scheme for Hamiltonian Parameter Estimation](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.160801)" (arXiv version [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04466)). The "feedback control" schemes proposed in these papers are schematically represented by the figures below.

[image: From Phys. Rev. Lett. 115, 110401]

[image: From Phys. Rev. Lett. 117, 160801]

In both of these schemes, the feedback is modeled as a bunch of unitary operators interspersed with the unitary evolution operator of the system of interest. This resembles dynamical decoupling scheme and a kind of "coherent control" but I can't understand in which sense this can be interpreted as a feedback control. No information is being fed back to the system either after a quantum measurement (no measurement feedback) or by an auxiliary control open quantum system (no coherent feedback). So why is it called "feedback"?

Comment: From the abstract, it is not clear what the author studies. It is told about a magnetic field, but in which experiment, configuration, it is not clear. What system is being studied?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the original paper, I just quoted the related part here:

> In practice, the true value of $x$ is a priori unknown. Instead, an estimated value $\hat{x}$ has to be used for the feedback controls; the controls $U_1=U_2=\cdots=U_{m-1}=$ $U_t^{\dagger}(\hat{x})$ need to be updated adaptively with the estimated value.

The rough idea is that the optimal unitary in your graph, that is $U_1,U_2...$ depends on the unknown parameter. Hence to apply those $U_1,U_2,...$, you need to apply them adaptively whence the word "feedback" comes from.